# Filter the list by inner list key

Tags: c#, list

I have a list object of `List<Student>`

```
Student
    StudentId
    StudentName
    List<Subject>
Subject
    SubjectId
    SubjectName
```

How can I filter the `List<Student>` by `SubjectId` returning the Students with the subject.

I have on the list is

```
Student1
    Math { SubjectId = 1 }
    Science { SubjectId = 2 }
    Speech { SubjectId = 3 }
Student2
    Math { SubjectId = 1 }
    Cheering { SubjectId = 4 }
Student3
    Science { SubjectId = 2 }
    Speech { SubjectId = 4 }
```

I want to filter the above object by `SubjectId = 1` and expect a returned object like

```
Student1
    Math { SubjectId = 1 }
Student2
    Math { SubjectId = 1 }
```

How do I query this on C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = (from s in students
          where s.Subjects.Any(subj => subj.SubjectID == yourValue)
          select new Student
          {
              Name = s.StudentName
              Subjects = s.Subjects.Where(subj => subj.SubjectID == yourValue).ToList());    
          }
```

Something like this (without much checking) and it could be done better for sure

Comment: this looks more closer to what I need, I'm testing this one right now.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
students.Where(s => s.Subjects.Any(su => su.SubjectId = 1));
```

Comment: Have made up some property/variable names here - might require a tweak.

Comment: Just as the one from Wint...you will give him all the subjects but it looks like he only wants the one that he is looking for

Comment: I also want to remove the Subjects that is not equal to SubjectId = 1

Comment: Yes, in which case look at Ivan's answer, which I've upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = from stu in students
        from sub in stu.Subjects
        where sub.SubjectId = 1
        select stu;
```

I didn't test it yet because i have no VS here.

Comment: This will give him all subjects but it looks like he only wants to have the one that matches the criteria

Comment: Yes, you are right. I probably would resort to 2 query clauses for this task. A single query bewilders me.